# how to make a function that receives a list of lists of numbers and returns the list has the highest number value in it?

Tags: python, list, python-3.7

```
def find_biggest(lst):
    my_list = []
    my_new_list = []
```

how do I go from here, what do I start with to reach the largest number in all of the lists?

for example: `find_biggest([[1, 2, 3], [10, -2], [1, 1, 1, 1]])` → is the list `[10, -2]` because `10` is the highest number value in all lists

Comment: the highest value of the number in all the lists

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: for examply : find_biggest([[1, 2, 3], [10, -2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]) → returns [10, -2] because the 10 is the highest number value in the lists

Answer (score 2):

you can use `max` function with `key` equal to `len` , to  get the sublist with maximum no of elements List item

```
return max(lst, key = max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to iterate across all lists in the list of lists and return the list with the maximum value:

```
def find_biggest(list_of_lists):
    biggest_num = float('-inf')
    index_of_list_with_biggest = 0

    for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
        current_list = list_of_lists[i]
        for item in current_list:
            if(item > biggest_num):
                biggest_num = item
                index_of_list_with_biggest = i
        
    return list_of_lists[index_of_list_with_biggest]





if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_biggest([[1, 2, 3], [10, -2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]))
```

Output:

```
[10, -2]
```